# Parsing log via logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm newbie to ELK. I'm trying to parse the log using Logstash and grok.

Logstash config:

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOG5424SD}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:Log_level}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Parameters}%{SPACE}\-%{SPACE}\[operation=%{WORD:operation},%{SPACE}duration=%{NUMBER:duration}%{SPACE}sec\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Parameters}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Parameters}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Parameters}%{SPACE}(?:[^:]+)caller:%{SPACE}%{IPV4:caller},%{SPACE}username:%{SPACE}%{WORD:username}(?:[^:]+)%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Parameters}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Parameters}%{SPACE}Headers:%{GREEDYDATA:Headers}%{SPACE}Payload:%{SPACE}{%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Payload}%{SPACE}}\n\n(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:java_stack_trace}\n\n" }
    }
}

output {
  file {
   path => ["/tmp/test_log/output/output.log"]
   codec => rubydebug
 }
}
```

Log:

```
2022-03-28 01:19:58,178 [default task-5117] INFO  LoggingFeature_LONGOPS - [operation=getClientStatus, duration=14.90 sec] REQ_IN
    ID: 304711
    Address: http://192.168.0.1:8080/test/test/services/getClientStatus [caller: 192.168.0.1, username: TEST_TEST]
    HttpMethod: POST
    Content-Type: application/json
    Headers: {Authorization=********, Accept=application/json, text/plain, */*, User-Agent=axios/0.21.4, connection=close, content-type=application/json, Host=192.168.0.1:8080, Conten$
    Payload:
{"data1":"7777777777","data2":1111}

Cpu usage (90 samples by 100 ms, total 9 sec):
java.lang.Thread.run (90) - 100%
 org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run (90) - 100%
  org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask (90) - 100%
```

On grokdebug.herokuapp.com it gives a normal response with all the required data, and directly in Logstash an error occurs after the first line:

```
{
     "operation" => "getClientStatus",
          "host" => "test",
     "Log_level" => "INFO",
    "@timestamp" => 2022-03-30T08:49:35.228Z,
    "Parameters" => "LoggingFeature_LONGOPS ",
      "duration" => "14.90",
     "timestamp" => "2022-03-28 01:19:58,178",
       "message" => "2022-03-28 01:19:58,178 [default task-5117] INFO  LoggingFeature_LONGOPS - [operation=getClientStatus, duration=14.90 sec] REQ_IN",
      "@version" => "1"
}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2022-03-30T08:49:35.231Z,
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
          "host" => "test",
       "message" => "    ID: 304711",
      "@version" => "1"
}
```

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong?

I tried using

```
(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:Parameters:}
```

specified the multiline codec in the input

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/test_log/input/*.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
      negate => true
      what => previous
    }
  }
}
```

also enabled the option

```
config.support_escapes: true
```

in logstash.yml

Comment: I think you've got to remove the last `\n\n` from your pattern. btw you can quickly test and edit your grok pattern here : https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: the stdin plugin read each line separately, so it will first send `2022-03-28 01:19:58,178 [default task-5117] INFO  LoggingFeature_LONGOPS - [operation=getClientStatus, duration=14.90 sec] REQ_IN` to the grok filter, then `    ID: 304711`. If you want to parse all the lines as one event, you'll have to use the [multiline codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) on your input

Comment: @baudsp Many thanks! That's what I need

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/test_log/input/*.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^%{DATE_EU}"
      negate => true
      what => previous
    }
}
```